# Unterminated string constant

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

My Description contains an apstrophe('). How to escape it.

```
<a href='javascript:select("<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(0), "'", "'") %>",
"<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(1), "'", "'") %>");' title="<%=selRpt%>">
<span class='img-view'></span></a>
```

`"<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(1), "'", "'") %>"` is the description part in my JSP Scriptlet which contains apstrophe(')

**My HTML View**

```
    <a href='javascript:select("JWCCA5",
"Worker's Compensation Form -  California Form 5020(New)");' 
title="Select Report"><span class='img-view'></span></a>
```

Comment: You'd think that the framework would have some way of HTML-escaping the text. Heck, even *PHP* can do that.

Comment: By the way, don't put JavaScript into the `href` argument. Use the `onclick` event

Comment: What is the intention of the `pageBean.replace()` method?

Comment: it would replace the value coming from the DB column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reserved HTML characters you should use [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp). An apostrophe is then reprecented as `&#39;`:

```
<a href='javascript:select(
  "<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(0), "'", "&#39;") %>", 
  "<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(1), "'", "&#39;") %>");' title="<%=selRpt%>"> 
<span class='img-view'></span></a>
```

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Use `\'`</strike>

Inside a HTML tag, you need to turn the string into HTML entities, so the quote becomes `&#039;`

Inside pure JavaScript, you could also escape the quote with a `\'`

Comment: `&quot;` is the way to go here, HTML doesn't allow backslash escaping. @John, replace "Worker's" with "Worker&quot;s".

Comment: @John you are not specifying the language you're using, but it almost certainly has an `addslashes` function of some sort to add backslashes, or a `htmlentities`  one to convert all special characters into their entity equivalents.

Comment: @Andy is correct, I overlooked that this is inside HTML code, so you need to look for the entities function in your language / framework

Answer (score 2):

Usually \' should work, but it seems that sometimes you need to use '' (double apostrophe).

Try this one:

```
<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(0), "'", "\'" %>
```

or:

```
<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(0), "'", "''"
```

One of them should work (from my experience).

For attributes within HTML tags, I would use " (quotation mark) rather than ' (apostrophe).

Comment: It depends where your string is coming from. I assume that "Worker's Compensation form" will be placed in some properties eventually (at least it should, I wouldn't hardcode it), in such case you should escape it in properties file. Otherwise simply escape it as you code.

Answer (score 1):

Call a function from the HTML, and put your JavaScript in that function. It'll get around your problem, but I think it's slightly better practice anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the unicode character code instead? (\u0027)

Comment: I expect you could use it anywhere you've got an apostrophe that's not intended to be a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the `'` with `#39;` before it is rendered.
You can do it in
 - the properties file from where this is coming from
 - in code in ASP

BTW, what are you trying in this line?

```
"<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(1), "'", "'") %>"
```

Perhaps

```
"<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(1), "'", "&#39;") %>"
```

should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

A normal JSP developer would [abandon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) old fashioned *scriptlets* and use JSTL [`c:out`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) or [`fn:escapeXml`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) instead. Both escapes [predefined XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) like `'` to `&#39;` and so on.

Here's an example with `fn:escapeXml`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
...
<a href="javascript:select('${fn:escapeXml(list.columns[0])}',
    '${fn:escapeXml(list.columns[1])}');" title="${title}">
```

You may only need to change the model to be more a fullworthy Javabean.